# What does tensorflow's tables_initializer do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

The documentation is not very clear [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/tables_initializer)
The vague description says that it initializes tables. What tables are those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables in TensorFlow generally refer to data structures supporting lookup operations, i.e. map-like collections. So far, these operations have lived under [`tf.contrib.lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup), but it seems the TensorFlow team are moving these to TensorFlow core (probably as part of the efforts towards TensorFlow 2.0, where `tf.contrib` will not be included). In fact, you can see classes that are actually already in core TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import lookup_ops  # This is inside core TensorFlow

print(tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable is lookup_ops.HashTable)
# True
```

[`tf.initializers.tables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/tables_initializer) being there in the documentation seems more of an accident right now, since the public API for lookup operations is still [`tf.contrib.lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup). That documentation page is caused by the `@tf_export` decorators in [`python/ops/lookup_ops.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/lookup_ops.py). As more of the API is moved, all the pieces of the documentation will fit better (although the documentation for that function could be a bit more descriptive anyway).

In any case, if you are not using lookup operations or data structures, it is probably not relevant to you.